# DateTime Compare Ignores Kind?

Tags: c#, datetime, utc

```
DateTime d1=new DateTime(2015, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
DateTime d2=new DateTime(2015, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Local);
Console.WriteLine(d1==d2);           // prints true
Console.WriteLine(d1<d2);            // prints false
Console.WriteLine(d1.CompareTo(d2)); // prints 0
Console.WriteLine(d1.ToUniversalTime()==d2.ToUniversalTime()); // prints false
```

This looks like a bug to me, if not [color me surprised](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment).

Do I have to call ToUniversalTime() for every comparison or is there a better alternative?

How do you avoid pitfalls like forgetting to call ToUniversalTime() or getting a wrong result because of DateTimeKind.Unspecified?

Comment: Not *exactly*, it's in the documentation - you have to ensure the times are in the same timezone. Besides, `DateTime` doesn't include any timezone info. You need `DateTimeOffset` for this

Comment: Docs clearly states this *Before comparing DateTime objects, make sure that the objects represent times in the same time zone. You can do this by comparing the values of their Kind properties.*

Comment: `NodaTime` to the rescue :)

Comment: And [here's the actual source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/datetime.cs,503) to show how simple the comparison actually is.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The MSDN documentation is quite clear that `DateTimeKind` is not taken into account using the Equality operator.

> The Equality operator determines whether two DateTime values are equal by comparing their number of ticks. **Before comparing DateTime objects, make sure that the objects represent times in the same time zone. You can do this by comparing the values of their Kind property**.

[MSDN - DateTime.Equality Operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.op_equality(v=vs.110).aspx)

You could write your own extension method to include the `DateTimeKind` comparison:

```
public static bool EqualsWithKind(this DateTime time, DateTime other)
{
      return time.Kind == other.Kind &&
             time == other;
}
```

Taking into account the comments from *Panagiotis Kanavos* and *James Thorpe* about `DateTimeOffset`:

***Use if the offsets are guaranteed to be the same as the local offset.***

```
public static bool EqualsWithTimezone(this DateTime time, DateTime other)
{
      return new DateTimeOffset(time) == new DateTimeOffset(other);
}
```

***Use if the offsets are NOT guaranteed to be the same:***

```
public static bool EqualsInclTimezone(this DateTime time, TimeSpan timeOffset, DateTime other, TimeSpan otherOffset)
{
      return new DateTimeOffset(time, timeOffset) == new DateTimeOffset(other, otherOffset);
}
```

Comment: Can you give me an alternative that avoids this pitfall?

Comment: Don't use DateTime, use DateTimeOffset which includes the tz offset. Better yet, use Noda Time which uses the actual timezone name and adjusts offsets for daylight savings. Indispensable for air travel calculations

Comment: @laktak: See my edit for avoiding the `DateTimeKind` comparison issue. Tho' consider whether it is the best for what you need to do.

Comment: @toadflakz this is insufficient for local times. Local times for different timezones will appear equal even when they are not. Even local times for the same timezone may be wrong if one of the dates is in winter time and the other is not.

Comment: Be wary of that extension method - that just guarantees that they're the same time and the same Kind.  They may still be the same time even if the Kinds are different.  `DateTimeOffset` should really be used here.

Comment: @JamesThorpe +1 DateTimeOffset at least. You need NodaTime though to find the correct offset for each timezone

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Indeed - it's a project I need to explore more as I've hit the limitations in core .NET a couple of times now

Comment: @toadflakz Your edit assumes that local time have the machine's current offset - similar to assuming a string uses the machine's system codepage only to find an incompatible string. That's not always the case (eg for times read from a database). That's also an issue with `ToUniversalTime() `, it assumes a certain offset.

Comment: @JamesThorpe Java is a little bit better but still lacking - that's why JodaTime was created (Noda started as a port of Joda).

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: Are you saying pass in the offsets as well to for the `DateTimeOffset` comparison?

Comment: @toadflakz that *may* be necessary because the constructor uses the *system's* offset. If the local times are *guaranteed* to be equal to the system's, that's not an issue. That breaks down in a lot of situations though - imagine user entered times in a web application hosted in a different timezone (east vs west). Too many assumptions and edge cases

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: I've added the overload and the warnings about offsets - hopefully anyone reading/using the answer will read the comments too.

Answer (score 2):

It's not exactly a bug but a shortcoming of `DateTime`. The `DateTime` type doesn't support timezone information apart from a local/UTC indicator. It says so in the docs - you have to ensure the dates are in the same timezone - not just having the same Kind. `DateTimeKind.Local` doesn't say anything about what timezone is really used.

If you care about timezones you should always use the [DateTimeOffset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) type. It was introduced in .NET 3.5 partly to address timezones. DateTimeOffset is equivalent to SQL Server's `datetimeoffset` type and contains the timezone offset along with the time, allowing comparisons and conversions between timezone *offsets*. This also allows you to store and use the complete time information in code and the database, avoiding conversion errors.

This is similar to using `nvarchar` instead of `varchar` to avoid codepages conversion errors.

A timezone may have different offsets though due to daylight savings. Daylight savings rules change from time to time also - Russian rules have changed 4 times at least in the last 10 years. Windows and .NET don't have a fix for this.

This can be an issue eg in the travel industry. In such cases you can use a library like [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org/), which contains the IANA timezone database with all known timezone rules.

Answer (score -2):

Looks correct to me.

1/1/2015 15:00:00 (utc) (also GMT - Equal to GMT Greenwich Mean Time)

1/1/2015 15:00:00 (local - lets say local time is in NYC)

these two times and dates ARE equal by comparison.

But convert the second one to UTC and it skips ahead 5 hours to become 
UTC/GMT

1/1/2015 20:00:00 - and  they are no longer equal!