# How does C# DateTime determine it's Now and Today times

Tags: c#, datetime

Couldn't find anything on the internet nor the documentation on this. Where does C# get it's `DateTime.Now` or `DateTime.Today` from? These are localized values. Is it determined by Windows? Or does IIS influence this? I want to know what exactly parses the real now time to C# and what can influence it.

---

#### Why I want to know this

I am having some weird API behavior where some things are returned hours before they should. Which is most likely related to time zones. VPS and client are in the same time zone so I am wondering what can influence such behavior.

I am doing a hard `...FromDate.Date <= DateTime.Today.Date` and for some reason I sometimes get records that are "from" tomorrow. Where `2021-02-21 <= 2021-02-20` seems to be "true". True meaning that the `DateTime.Today` seems to be off. Only seeing this behavior around after 10 PM so hours before actual midnight suggesting it has something to do with time zones.

If you have any idea on this behavior please tell me

Comment: It uses the RTC on the PC via Windows API calls (probably by calling `GetSystemTime()`)

Comment: @MatthewWatson does that mean the C# local now time should always be the same as the windows time you see on the bottom right. With out of the box settings not changing anything

Comment: It calls the relevant Operating System APIs of the host machine.

Comment: Yes, `Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now)` should be the same.

Comment: [DateTime.Kind is ignored on comparisons](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28602941/87698), so it *appears* that the problem lies with your `FromDate`, not with `DateTime.Today`. May I suggest logging both values to find the cause of this?

Comment: @Heinzi debugged this thoroughly and it's one of those can't reproduce scenario's but on customers phone it definitely does happen. Can't debug into our production environment. But I did verify the data. It's a really weird issue, which I am assigned to fix.

Comment: You can look at the actual implementation: https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/datetime.cs

Comment: Commenting since it doesn't answer the question but I find it is best practice to always use `DateTime.UTCNow`. If you treat all times as UTC at all times then you will never need to worry about local times, timezones and other things. If you need to display local times in the UI somewhere then convert them to local times in the display code.

Comment: @Chris thanks, but in this particular scenario it should be localized.

Answer (score 6):

Thanks to @Matthew Watson for helping me get here.

#### For anyone in the future

The `DateTime.Now` is received from the system. First it will get `UtcNow` and then applying a local offset (if there is any).

See [source code line 1051](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/datetime.cs#L1051)

The `DateTime.Today` property just returns `DateTime.Now.Date`

See [source code line 1262](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/datetime.cs#L1262)

---

UtcNow is received by the internal extern method `GetSystemTimeWithLeapSecondsHandling`. Which I couldn't find a implementation for.

See [source code](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/5697c29004a34d80acdaf5742d7e699022c64ecd/mscorlib/system/datetime.cs#L1154)

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, `DateTime.Now` or `DateTime.Today` checks your server's time. If you are running your application from the server, most likely it is checking your server time

Comment: Thanks. Any links to official documentation?

Comment: It doesn't access a server time, it accesses the local PC time. Windows itself may occasionally set the local PC time to a server time (if it's on a domain, for example) or it may set it to the time from a time server, but DateTime.Now doesn't go to a server.

Comment: My Mistake @RoyBerris https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.now?view=net-5.0
According to the documentation of this, it is said that it takes from the computer. If you are still having problem, with the DateTime issue, I recommend to have a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset?view=net-5.0

Answer (score 0):

So technically, according to Microsoft documentation, the DateTime.Now property returns the DateTime object that is stored on the machine to the current date and time, interpreted as local time. On the other side, DateTime.Today, is an object set to today's date, with the time component set to 00:00:00. The Today property is appropriate for use in programs that only deal with dates as it returns the current date without the present time. I believe what influences this is the time set on your local machine, I doubt that IIS influences this. However, those values can be influenced if you're running your application on a server.

Comment: could we conclude that `DateTime.Today = DateTime.Now.Date`? Or are there differences?

Comment: @RoyBerris The actual implementation of `DateTime.Today` is simply `DateTime.Now.Date`