# C# DateTime.MinValue is handled differently by PostgreSQL, EFCore or Npgsql?

Tags: c#, postgresql, npgsql, timestamp-with-timezone

I am saving a C# `DateTime.MinValue` to a PostgreSQL column of type `timestamp with timezone` with `EFCore 7.05` and `Ngpsql 7.04`

- `Date = {1/01/0001 12:00:00 AM}`
- `Kind = Utc`

When I load the column, the value becomes

- `Date = {1/01/0001 12:00:00 AM}`
- `Kind = Unspecified`

Other non-default values can be saved and loaded fine with the correct DateTime.Kind value.
Does anybody know what is happening in EFCore, npgsql and Postgres? Which one should I look into?

Comment: What version of EF Core are you using?

Comment: Not sure, but EF may do this. I'm using MSSQL, and datetime values are saved w/o timezone, and when EF fetches the datetime 'unspecified' is always added (this behaviour can be customized). Is datetimeoffset not more appropriate if you care about timezones?

Comment: @GuruStron EFCore 7.05, npgsql 7.04

Comment: @sommmen I am new to the whole tech stack and have assumed that a C# DateTime Value of Kind Utc will be saved to PostgreSQL as Utc and later on loaded as Utc into C#. I even tested and verified that this is the way it worked until I had a `DateTime.Minimum` value which lost its timezone when saved and loaded again.

Comment: Since its `DateTime.MinValue`, why do you care? even equals doesn't seem to care: https://dotnetfiddle.net/pcvNHL

Comment: @RandRandom, it is a long story. I've created my own `UtcTime` type trying to enforce timezone safety across a large code base. It supports MinValue as a valid value. I'd expect the infrastructure layer also support `MinValue`

Comment: hmm, interesting that `==` operator does not care about kind. I am surprised. Maybe one more reason to not to use the builtin `DateTime` type :)

Comment: Notice: when I wrote my comment I thought that Kind only gets ignored because `DateTime.MinValue` is something special - this seems to be incorrect as `Kind` always gets ignored see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28602941/datetime-compare-ignores-kind

Comment: Maybe consider NodaTime: https://nodatime.org/

Comment: Yeah, I have considered it and maybe had made the wrong decision to write my own date type.

Comment: The `DateTime.Ticks` value is zero for `DateTime.MinValue` so perhaps it's treating a value of 0 specially for some reason. What happens with a tick value of 1?

Comment: @XiaoguoGe > C# DateTime Value of Kind Utc will be saved to PostgreSQL as Utc and later on loaded as Utc into C#. 

Firstly, generally prefer `DateTimeOffset` if you want things to be timezone aware in .net. I'm not sure how storing the datetime goes, maybe it will always become utc, maybe it will ignore timezones all together, you'd have to test. In MSSQL the backing is just an integer, so i assume no local/utc conversion happens and the dt gets saved as-is. In all cases however, EF does not specify the kind when reading and you'd have to set the appropriate kind value yourself

Comment: Is there any reason this field is not nullable? Why use `MinValue` as a marker value, rather than `null`, which is perfectly designed for that purpose?

Comment: @Charlieface Yes, making it nullable solves the problem by avoiding using this value. But `DateTime.MinValue`, being a valid value for `DateTime`, should not be treated as special. Someone has made a mistake in the chain of `EFCore`, `Npgsql`, and `PostgreSQL`.

Comment: @MatthewWatson a tick value of 1 is saved as `0001-01-01 10:04:52.000001+10:04:52` while a tick value of 0 is saved as `-infinity`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DateTime.MinValue almost isn't ever used to represent an actual timestamp, but rather a special marker or value that's smaller than all other values. The corresponding value in PostgreSQL is `-infinity`, which is why Npgsql performs that conversion. The conversion is performed both ways, both when you write DateTime.MinValue to PG, and when you read `-infinity` from PG as a .NET DateTime.

Note that DateTime.MinValue has Kind=Unspecified, not Utc; this is why reading -infinity results in Kind=Unspecified.

Note that the conversion behavior can be disabled via a special compatibility switch, but that's not recommended: that means that you'll get an actual timestamp of 1/1/0001 in the database rather than -infinity.

See [these Npgsql docs](https://www.npgsql.org/doc/types/datetime.html#infinity-values) for more info.

Comment: Do you think it is more intuitive to map `-infinity` also to Kind `Utc` instead of `Unspecified` when the PostgreSQL column is `timestamp with timezone`? All the other values are mapped to Kind Utc, `MinValue` should not be any different other than that it is the smallest value.
The DateTime equality operator ignores Kind, which is wrong in my opinion, so this change won't affect the meaning of the Value but will make the timezone consistent across all values.

Comment: You're not wrong - I can see a case for returning `DateTime.SpecifyKind(DateTime.MinValue, DateTimeKind.Utc)` for `-infinity` for `timestamptz` columns...

Comment: However, I think generally DateTime.MinValue is a set, special value (sentinel), whose Kind shouldn't matter at all; it's just something you check to see if it's MinValue. I'm also a bit concerned that we wouldn't actually return DateTime.MinValue: even if the equality operator ignores it, the Utc version wouldn't actually be DateTime.MinValue...

Comment: I'm curious, apart from the inconsistency of Unspecified being returned for a timestamptz column, what concrete problems are you seeing with the current scheme?

Comment: No, except Kind. I don't see any other problems. Npgsql is an easy-to-use and easy-to-understand library. I was new to PostgreSQL and Npgsql, and managed to be productive after only a couple of days of research and learning. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for the kind words, I'm happy Npgsql works well for you! But I was asking more specifically what concrete problem the Unspecified Kind is causing you - or is it just the fact that it's inconsistent?

Comment: Yes, it is just the inconsistency. I have developed my own type, `UtcTime` to enforce timezone handling in the domain layer. This `UtcTime` is serialized/deserialized to/from a postgresql timestamp column. In the domain layer, `MinValue` is a valid value for the type. There is nothing special about it other than that it is `small`. I'd like it to be not special also for serialization.

Comment: Or put it in another way, a valid `UtcTime` value is serialized into DB and then read back, it becomes invalid and is not accepted by the `UtcTime` type validation.

Comment: OK, thanks for the context. Having your own timestamp type is a bit... much - I wouldn't generally recommend it. If you're concerned with enforcing e.g. that the Kind is correct, you're probably better off just using NodaTime which is generally superior and where the types themselves enforce Kind distinctions (i.e. Instant vs. LocalDateTime). Everything is simpler there.

Comment: Otherwise you can of course handle MinValue/MaxValue in a special way in your custom timestamp type/conversion. But again, I don't think that having your own timestamp type is a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Might be because the minimum value stored by postgresql is  **January 1, 4713 BC**, documented [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html).

And for C# the minimum date is **1/01/0001**, documented [here](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-datetime#:%7E:text=The%20default%20and%20the%20lowest,value%20to%20a%20DateTime%20object.).

This might be causing **DateTime.MinValue** set to Unspecified.